# Jekyll issue with overlapping scopes in _config.yml

Tags: jekyll

I have an issue using scopes in my `_config.yml` file:

In a multilingual blog, I want to use a given layout for all posts, and then customize permalinks for each language with a more specialized scope. Here is my configuration:

```
defaults:
    -
        # defaults for all files in the project
        scope:
            path: ""
        values:
            layout: my-page-layout
    -
        # defaults for all posts in the project
        scope:
            path: ""
            type: posts
        values:
            layout: my-post-layout
    -
        # defaults for all english posts in the project
        scope:
            path: en
            type: posts
        values:
            permalink: /en/:year/:month/:title/
    -
        # defaults for all french posts in the project
        scope:
            path: fr
            type: posts
        values:
            permalink: /fr/:year/:month/:title/
```

English posts under the path `en` effectively have the right layout (`my-post-layout`), but not the french posts under the path `fr` which have the default layout (`my-page-layout`).

Looks like the scope corresponding to the pair "fr/posts" overrides the default values for all posts, while this is not the case for the scope corresponding to the pair "en/posts".

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

The directory structure of my jekyll project looks like this (I removed unrelevant files):

```
./
├──_layouts/
│  ├──my-page-layout.html
│  └──my-post-layout.html
│
├──en/
│  ├──_posts/
│  │  └──2016-12-01-my-post-in-english.md
│  │
│  └──my-page-in-english.html
│
├──fr/
│  ├──_posts/
│  │  └──2016-12-01-mon-post-en-français.md
│  │
│  └──ma-page-en-français.html
│
└──_config.yml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit :

Reading from your code :

```
defaults:
    -
        scope:
            path: ""
        values:
            layout: wasthishelpful-page
            lang: en
    -
        scope:
            path: fr
        values:
            lang: fr
    -
        scope:
            path: ""
            type: posts
        values:
            layout: wasthishelpful-post
    -
        scope:
            path: en/_posts
        values:
            permalink: /en/:year/:month/:title/
    -
        scope:
            path: fr/_posts
        values:
            permalink: /fr/:year/:month/:title/
```

And from [jekyll code](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/frontmatter_defaults.rb#L140), we can see that we have a precedence problem.

The second rule applies to **/fr** path, but will not be overriden by third rule that applies to **/** path.

The solution is to declare your third rule before the second one by inverting them.

```
defaults:
    -
        scope:
            path: ""
        values:
            layout: wasthishelpful-page
            lang: en
    -
        scope:
            path: ""
            type: posts
        values:
            layout: wasthishelpful-post
    -
        scope:
            path: fr
        values:
            lang: fr
    ...
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I am storing my posts in **en/_posts** and **fr/posts** (I edited my question to precise the directory structure). I tried your proposition, but it doesn't work: english posts still have the correct layout, while french posts don't

Comment: Edited my answer. You missed a **s** in **_posts**.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, as in my comment. The posts are in **en/_posts** and **fr/_posts**, and that's the paths I used in `_config.yml`, like in your answer